# Filter out columns before grouping by in Pandas

Tags: pandas, csv

I am loading data from a CSV file:

```
df = pd.read_csv('myFile.csv', encoding = "ISO-8859-1", 
                        parse_dates=['Start Date', 'End Date'])
```

and then I am grouping the data and aggregating:

```
df['Clean'] = (df['Value'] - df['Value2']).round(decimals=0)


#Group by and aggregate (return Earliest Start Date, Latest End Date and SUM of the Values)
groupedBy = df.groupby([df['ID'], df['Name'].fillna('Other'),df['Site']]).agg({'Start Date': 'min', 'End Date': 'max', 'Value': 'sum', 'Value2': 'sum', 'Clean': 'sum'})
```

All I am trying to do is to add an IF statement in order to exclude some rows. So, if the column "A" fields contain the "XXX" value, it will return the rows:

```
if df['A'].str.contains('xxx'):
    groupedBy = df.groupby([df['ID'], df['Name'].fillna('Other'), df['Site']]).agg({'Start Date': 'min', 'End Date': 'max', 'Value': 'sum', 'Value2': 'sum', 'Clean': 'sum'})
```

and it fails. I tried searching on stack and using other versions with no success. Do I have to include that in the `agg` part of my grouping? Why is the IF statement failing?

Comment: `df[df['A'].str.contains('xxx')].groupby().agg(.....)`

Comment: @Wen That worked. You can post it as an answer. :)

Comment: You want me post it as an answer ? Ok ~

Comment: @Wen That resolved it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

filter your `DataFrame` before `groupby`

```
df[df['A'].str.contains('xxx')].\
     groupby([df['ID'], df['Name'].fillna('Other'),df['Site']]).\
      agg({'Start Date': 'min', 'End Date': 'max', 'Value': 'sum', 'Value2': 'sum', 'Clean': 'sum'})
```